# how to read data from the GPS tk206

Tags: gps

I have a Chinese GPS TK206
He sends me to IP data which I can not decipher:
(087071820702BP05352887071820702130501J0d03 | 9542 | 26006 | 000000000001050000000010000000L00000000)

I know that the first part is the device's IMEI 087071820702

does anyone know how to read with the GPS coordinates?

Comment: See user manual page 11 & 12 : http://www.gpstracker7.com/upfile/download/2013012217431158101.pdf

Comment: Thank you for help but my data structure is different than the documentation maybe it's because I own version of tk206OBD

Comment: @P__ did you resolved your issues.?

Comment: @SAndrew Hi, Yes, it sends such GPS data if it does not know its position.
If the GPS catches the signal, it sends the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
Given by me in the first post structure of the data is the only in cases when GPS is not found or does not change locations. When GPS is moving sends the correct structure with location

Comment: Do you have any information about the protocol? I can't find anything. Thanks

Comment: Which type of cable you are using to connect it to laptop.?

Answer (score 0):

This is the TK103 protocol. More details can be found here: https://www.traccar.org/protocols/